# exclude particular category in api

Tags: posts, categories, rest-api, api, json

How do I exclude a particular category in the API?

For all categories - I may use the following:

```
https://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&per_page=100
```

*What if I need across all the categories except for category-10?*

I am using JavaScript at the front.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out, just in case it might be helpful for anyone in future:

There is an option available to exclude a particular category - categories_exclude

So, the new rest API would be:

```
https://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&per_page=100&categories_exclude=10
```